# php - How do I fix this illegal offset type error

Tags: php, arrays

I'm getting

> illegal offset type

error for every iteration of this code. Here's the code :

```
$s = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++){
    $source = $xml->entry[$i]->source;
    $s[$source] += 1;    
}

print_r($s)
```

Comment: Warning: almost all answers (except zombat's) assume that `$source` is an instance of `SimpleXML` and provide information that only applies to that specific situation. While that was eventually the case, the question didn't state it and whoever comes here for reference should take this into account.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

*Illegal offset type* errors occur when you attempt to access an array index using an **object** or an **array** as the index key.

Example:

```
$x = new stdClass();
$arr = array();
echo $arr[$x];
//illegal offset type
```

Your `$xml` array contains an object or array at `$xml->entry[$i]->source` for some value of `$i`, and when you try to use that as an index key for `$s`, you get that warning.  You'll have to make sure `$xml` contains what you want it to and that you're accessing it correctly.

Comment: the source contains html, does that class as an object?

Comment: Did you create the `$xml` variable using some kind of XML parser?  simple_xml or DOMDocument?  In that case, then it's likely that the source node is actually some kind of dom element object.

Comment: i'm using simplexml_load_string. does that help?

Comment: Your HTML might have been parsed as XML, and likely all your tags became nodes.  For example, if you had an HTML snippet of "<div>Hi</div>" as your source property, then you've probably got something like `$xml->entry[$i]->source->div`.  If you want to parse HTML into a DOM structure, `DomDocument` has a `loadHTML()` function that handles HTML much better than SimpleXML.  Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Comment: thanks for that. I've used str_replace to strip the html and it works.

Comment: i had this problem when trying to use $var1[$var2]. $var was an object and of course, that was throwing an error.

Answer (score 27):

Use `trim($source)` before  `$s[$source]`.

Comment: I think this is the right answer for this question, not [that of zombat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732451/php-how-do-i-fix-this-illegal-offset-type-error#answer-2732502)

Comment: Trimming an object is just a non-obvious way to cast it to string (the straightforward one would be `(string)$source`) and results depends entirely on its [__toString()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) implementation. It works if you have a `SimpleXML` object (something apparently assumed by everybody but never really stated in the question).

Comment: If this is issue is related with __toString() implementation call trim() is not clean solution. It is confusing.

Comment: you can also try a `gettype($source)` which would probably return `object` not `string` or `number` as expected.

Answer (score 5):

check $xml->entry[$i] exists and is an object
before trying to get a property of it

```
 if(isset($xml->entry[$i]) && is_object($xml->entry[$i])){
   $source = $xml->entry[$i]->source;          
   $s[$source] += 1;
 }
```

or $source might not be a legal array offset but an array, object, resource or possibly null

Comment: The only right answer. You have to check the existence of the element in the array. If it does not exist, you cannot access it's properties.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably less than  20 entries in your xml.

change the code to this

```
for ($i=0;$i< sizeof($xml->entry); $i++)
...
```

Comment: An undefined integer index doesn't generate an "Illegal offset" warning, you'd get an "Undefined index" E_NOTICE instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. As I got a Character from my XML child I had to convert it first to a String (or Integer, if you expect one). The following shows how I solved the problem.

```
foreach($xml->children() as $newInstr){
        $iInstrument = new Instrument($newInstr['id'],$newInstr->Naam,$newInstr->Key);
        $arrInstruments->offsetSet((String)$iInstrument->getID(), $iInstrument);
    }
```