# Illegal offset type error when => value is omitted

Tags: php

Line 3 of the code below fails if I omit the `=> $v` portion. I get the following error:

`Warning: Illegal offset type in /home/site/page.php on line 404`

When the `[$k]` in line 5 is changed to `['$k']`, i receive the following error.

`Notice: Undefined index: $k in /home/site/page.php on line 404`

When it is like below with the the full `$k => $v` everything works though. I don't even use `$v`. Why do I need it in the `foreach` loop to make it work then?

```
<? if ( $arr[ 'status'][ 'chain'] ) { 
     foreach ( $arr[ 'status'][ 'chain'] as $k => $v) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="line_item_data status_td">
                <?= $ arr[ 'status'][ 'chain'][$k][ 'message'] ?>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <img src="images/green_check.gif" width="20" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    <? } 
} ?>
```

I did see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2732502/1252748), but don't know that it really applies. Thanks so much!

Comment: read this - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: may i ask why this was downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construct `$k => $v` is used to iterate an array's keys and values in a `foreach` construct.  You can iterate using the values `$v` alone, but you cannot iterate over the keys alone `$k`.  If you used the following:

```
foreach ($arr['status']['chain'] as $k)
```

...the foreach loop is syntactically valid but `$k` would be populated with the array *value* rather than the key.  In that case, the array element `$ arr[ 'status'][ 'chain'][$k][ 'message']` does not exist since `$k` does not hold a key valid in the array `$arr['status']['chain']`.

#### However, this can be much simpler...

Inside the loop, `$v` holds the array element you are attempting to index, so you merely need to access it as:

```
<?= $v['message'] ?>
```

That is the equivalent of `$arr['status']['chain'][$k]['message']`.  So ultimately it isn't `$v` that you don't need in your loop, but rather it is `$k` you don't need.

```
 // Iterate the values only. Keys aren't actually needed.
 foreach ( $arr[ 'status'][ 'chain'] as $v) {
     // snip html markup..
            <?= $v[ 'message'] ?>
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Either way you do it, you're looping through every item in the array.

If you just do foreach $k, you're setting $k to each VALUE in the array, ignoring the keys

If you keep it as $k => $v, you're setting $k to each KEY, and $v to each VALUE attached to the key.

So for example, you have an array that looks like this:

```
$arr=array(
    1=>'a',
    2=>'b',
    3=>'c'
);
```

And do:

```
foreach($arr as $k){
    echo "k is $k <br>";
}
```

the output would be:

```
k is a
k is b
k is c
```

Whereas if you do

```
foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
    echo "k is $k and v is $v<br>";
}
```

the output would be:

```
k is 1 and v is a
k is 2 and v is b
k is 3 and v is c
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because $k is a value, but you're using it as a key. Instead, write:

```
 <? if ( $arr[ 'status'][ 'chain'] ) { 
     foreach ( $arr[ 'status'][ 'chain'] as $k) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="line_item_data status_td">
                <?= $k[ 'message'] ?>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <img src="images/green_check.gif" width="20" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    <? } 
} ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The value has always to be specified when using `foreach`, *it's the key that is optional*.

As such,

```
foreach ($array as $k => $v)
```

...then `$k` is the key, and `$v` is the value. If you do:

```
foreach ($array as $k)
```

...then `$k` becomes the *value*, not the key. If you want just the key, you can do:

```
while (list($key) = each($array)) {
    echo $key;
}
```

...or:

```
while (key($array) && next($array)) {
    echo $key;
}
```