# php Illegal offset type in isset or empty

Tags: php, html

I have this code that was working initially, but does not work after I restarted my computer.

The error I am getting is:

> Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in D:\xampp\htdocs\cookieboylive\classes\Session.php on line 4

There's 3 files on my site - Index, Login, Register. Index page checks if users is logged in, but I don't think it has anything to do with the problem.

Here's the current code:

### The main register/login.php page

```
require_once 'core/init.php';

if(Input::exists()) {
    if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

        $validate = new Validate();
        $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
            'username' => array('required' => true),
            'password' => array('required' => true)
        ));

        if($validation->passed()) {
            $user = new User();
            $login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), Input::get('password'));

            if($login) {
                Redirect::to('index.php');
            } else {
                echo '<p>Sorry, login failed.</p>';
            }
        } else {
            foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
                echo $error, '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
}

if(Input::exists()) {
    if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {
        $validate = new Validate();
        $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
            'username' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 2,
                'max' => 20,
                'unique' => 'users'
            ),
            'password' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 6
            ),
            'password_again' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'matches' => 'password'
            ),
            'name' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 2,
                'max' => 50
            )
        ));

        if($validation->passed()) {
            $user = new User();

            $salt = Hash::salt(32);

            try {

                $user->create(array(
                    'username' => Input::get('username'),
                    'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
                    'salt' => $salt,
                    'name' => Input::get('name'),
                    'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    'group' => 1
                ));

                Session::flash('home', 'Register SUCCESS');
                Redirect::to('index.php');

            } catch(Exception $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
                echo $error, '<br>';
            }
        }

    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/register_login_styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/animate-custom.css">        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="container_demo" >
    <a class="hiddenanchor" id="toregister"></a>
    <a class="hiddenanchor" id="tologin"></a>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="login" class="animate form">
            <form  action="" method="post">
                <div class="field">
                    <h1>Log in</h1>
                    <p>
                        <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u" >Username </label>
                        <input id="username" name="username" required="required" type="text" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="password" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Password </label>
                        <input id="password" name="password" required="required" type="password" placeholder="Password">
                    </p>
                    <p class="keeplogin">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="loginkeeping" id="loginkeeping" value="loginkeeping">
                        <label for="loginkeeping">Keep me logged in</label>
                    </p>
                    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
                    <p class="login button">
                        <input type="submit" value="Login">
                    </p>
                    <p class="change_link">
                        Not a member yet ?
                        <a href="#toregister" class="to_register">Join us</a>
                    </p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="register" class="animate form">
            <form  action="" method="post">
                <h1> Sign up </h1>
                <p>
                    <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u">Username</label>
                    <input id="username" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('username')); ?>" name="username" required="required" type="text" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="password" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Your password </label>
                    <input id="password" name="password" required="required" type="password" placeholder="Password">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="password_again" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Please confirm your password </label>
                    <input id="password_again" name="password_again" required="required" type="password" placeholder="Password again">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="name" class="youmail" data-icon="n" >Name</label>
                    <input id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('name')); ?>" required="required" type="text" placeholder="Name" autocomplete="off">
                </p>
                <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
                <p class="signin button">
                    <input type="submit" value="Sign up">
                </p>
                <p class="change_link"> 
                    Already a member ?
                    <a href="#tologin" class="to_register"> Go and log in </a>
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>  
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Session.php

```
<?php
class Session {
    public static function exists($name) {
        return (isset($_SESSION[$name])) ? true : false;
    }

    public static function put($name, $value) {
        return $_SESSION[$name] = $value;
    }

    public static function get($name) {
        return $_SESSION[$name];
    }

    public static function delete($name) {
        if(self::exists($name)) {
            unset($_SESSION[$name]);
        }
    }

    public static function flash($name, $string = '') {
        if(self::exists($name)) {
            $session = self::get($name);
            self::delete($name);
            return $session;
        } else {
            self::put($name, $string);
        }
    }
}
```

### User.php

```
<?php
class User {
    private $_db,
            $_data,
            $_sessionName,
            $_isLoggedIn;

    public function __construct($user = null) {
        $this->_db = DB::getInstance();

        $this->_sessionName = Config::get('session/session_name');

        if(!$user) {
            if(Session::exists($this->_sessionName)) {
                $user = Session::get($this->_sessionName);

                if($this->find($user)) {
                    $this->_isLoggedIn = true;
                } else {
                    // Pr0cess logout
                }

            } else {
                $this->find($user);
            }
        }
    }

    public function create($fields = array()) {
        if(!$this->_db->insert('users', $fields)) {
            throw new Exception('There was a problem creating an account.');
        }
    }

    public function find($user = null) {
        if($user) {
            $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';
            $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));

            if($data->count()) {
                $this->_data = $data->first();
                return true;
            } 
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function login($username = null, $password = null) {
        $user = $this->find($username);

        if($user) {
            if($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)) {
                Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function data() {
        return $this->_data;
    }

    public function isLoggedIn() {
        return $this->_isLoggedIn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `trigger_error("DEBUG: ".gettype($name),E_USER_ERROR);` just inside the `Session::exists` function (on the line before the error). This should tell you the type of `$name`, and help us solve the problem.

Comment: have you added session_start()

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732451/php-how-do-i-fix-this-illegal-offset-type-error

Comment: im getting Fatal error: DEBUG: array in D:\xampp\htdocs\cookieboylive\classes\session.php on line 4 by adding the trigger_error

Answer (score 7):

> I'm getting Fatal error: DEBUG: array ...

That means `$name` is an array, which is obviously an illegal string offset. `$_SESSION[array()]` does not work. Make sure you're passing the right value to `Session::exists()`.

Answer (score 4):

I tried most of the solutions suggested above.  In actual fact the answer is not in the spelling but is in the fact that, as was pointed out above, the $name variable in the exists function is actually an array.

```
public static function exists($name) {
    return (isset($_SESSION[$name])) ? true : false;
}
```

The simple fix is to append [0] to [$name] so it becomes [$name][0] which returns the value associated with it and the one you want to see.  Works for me.  Why it worked in the video, I can't figure out; may be a configuration thing.

Answer (score 2):

I recognize the context you are dealing with, a tutorial PHP login/registration project from Skillfeed. In fact I  had the very same error that led me to a google search on the same error - I ended on this stackoverflow thread by You.

I couldn't find the answers very helpful but I looked through the classes of my project and I found the source of my problem in another class than your 3 classes shown in here.

That is in Token.php :

```
public static function check($token){
    $tokenName = Config::get('sesson/token_name');

    if(Session::exists($tokenName) && $token === Session::get($tokenName)){
        Session::delete($tokenName);
        return true;
    }

    return false;   
}
```

The problem was a simple misspelling , notice the get() function with its string parameter 'sesson/token_name', it should have been 'session/token_name'. Once I fixed this it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

It simply means the type of the variable (int, bool, array,..) you are passing does not aligns with expected parameter type in empty or isset.

Answer (score 0):

You have not typed the $name variable and that`s should be problem.

**Try this which will check also $name variable**:

```
return !empty($name) && is_string($name) && isset($_SESSION[$name]) ? true : false;
```

Just play with some situations or implement typing into you code.

Answer (score 0):

*"Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty"* may be shown if key-variable is not string. Example:

```
foreach ($xml->attributes() as $attrname => $attrval) 
    {
        if($attrname == "Name") $Name = $attrval;
        if(isset($_GET[$Name])) //catch Warning
            ...
```

Because gettype($Name) --> object.

Use type conversion to string:

```
        if(isset((string)$_GET[$Name])) //pass Perfect
```