# Use a loop to look through POST variables

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a POST method that will receive a value from a table (that is dynamically generated). This value will be equal to a company name, and a hidden field will be there that is equal to company name + "id" appended to it.

Here's my code:

```
if(isset($_POST))
{
    foreach ( $users as $balance_user ) {
        if(isset($_POST[$balance_user]))
        {
            //update user meta with new balance
            $newBalance = $_POST[$balance_user];
            $postedID = $_POST[$balance_user.'id'];
            update_user_meta($postedID, 'balance', $newBalance);
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting the error **Illegal offset type in isset or empty**. Can I not pass variables in that way? For example if a company is called Acme, and that particularly named input has a value in it, I want to loop through all of the companies in the POST method, and if that part of the loop equals the company passed in the variable, it should do something.

Comment: What is the value of `$balance_user`?

Comment: What is the value of $users

Comment: Are you only getting the error once, or many times?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php Illegal offset type in isset or empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22298454/php-illegal-offset-type-in-isset-or-empty)

Comment: A web search for "Illegal offset type in isset or empty" would tell you that  the key you are using in `$_POST` is not a valid key for use as an array offset. `$balance_user` must be a scalar value. It cannot be an array, or object, or callable, etc.

Comment: Sorry, $users is an array with a list of users and $balance_user will be the value posted by the form.

Answer (score 0):

Add these three lines to see the data, as others have indicated, clearly you are assuming some value is in $balance_user which is not there, or is different.

```
echo '<pre>:';
var_dump($balance_user);
echo ':</pre>';
if(isset($_POST[$balance_user]))
```

The pre makes it easier to read the debugging output. the :..: will show null values.

Once you run that, you will probably discover that one of your entries in $users is empty.

The output order will show you where that empty user value is.

However:

```
$postedID = $_POST[$balance_user.'id'];
```

That could be the error source as well, is there a post value that is. say, $balance_user == fred

```
fredid
```

if there isn't, of course you will instantly get that error. You aren't giving the line number of the error so I can't tell which it is, the line number will show it instantly.

Comment: This is advice how to debug, not an answer!

Comment: I disagree, you can't answer this without debugging it, and the debugger output will immediately give the answer. There's an assumption in the poster's code about values being present which  are not present that debugging will expose. Also, it's quite likely that in fact, it's the second item, ie, appending 'id' to the post key, that is causing the issue, though there's not enough information to know for sure. Since the user apparently has not debugged this, the assumption is, they don't know how to debug it.

Comment: As you wrote yourself, you can't answer it without debugging. True, but it's not an answer. It's a comment

Comment: Not to argue it, but showing how to debug to get the answer is the answer assuming the debugger data reveals the bug. Also, comment boxes do not lend themselves to posting code blocks. The inability to debug is the cause of the question, ergo, showing how to debug is actually the real answer. Only the poster can see this answer because only the poster has the $user data, and knows the full post fields, and can see the results of running debuggers on it.

Comment: You guys are being circular, comment boxes do no support adequate formatting easily for code. As you'll note, no answer appears here besides mine because the answer is created by debugging, and the debugging is the solution in this type of case. Other people who come in for the 'answer' will see the debugging data, apply it, and find their solution. which is the purpose of providing 'answers' on stackoverflow, to provide solutions on how to solve problems. If there had been a 'solution' possible without the debugging data, it would have appeared, debugging is a core tool for answers.

Comment: Sorry, I meant debugging method. I have to say, as a programmer, when faced with a problem that requires debugging methodology, and the resultant data that method provides, to solve, the notion that this methodology is not an answer, well... enough said.