# select2 array from API

Tags: json, jquery-select2

is it possible to set a json decoded array as choices for a genemu_jqueryselect2_choice input ?

I tried with the following:

```
$search = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('departure', 'genemu_jqueryselect2_choice', array(
            'choices' => $airports,
            'label' => 'Departure',
        ))
        ->getForm()
    ;
```

which causes a

```
Warning: Illegal offset type
```

$airports is an array of stdClass objects, which look like this once decoded:

```
array:1711 [▼
  0 => {#1036 ▼
+"lfi": "XXXXXXXX1"
+"icao": "ENEG"
+"iata": null
+"faaCode": null
+"name": " Eggemoen"
+"city": " Eggemoen"
+"countryCode": "FR"
+"latitudeDecimal": "-60.2272220"
+"longitudeDecimal": "10.3058330"
+"utcStdConversion": null
}
1 => {#1037 ▼
+"lfi": "SP80307"
+"icao": "LECO"
+"iata": "LCG"
+"faaCode": null
+"name": "A CORUNA"
+"city": "LA CORUNA"
+"countryCode": "ES"
+"latitudeDecimal": "43.3020611"
+"longitudeDecimal": "-8.3772556"
+"utcStdConversion": "+1"
}
... and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to borrow the answer from this SO [php - How do I fix this illegal offset type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732451/php-how-do-i-fix-this-illegal-offset-type-error)

> llegal offset type errors occur when you attempt to access an array index using an object or an array as the index key.

Example:

```
$x = new stdClass();
$arr = array();
echo $arr[$x];
//illegal offset type
```

You cannot use arrays or objects as keys. Doing so will result in a warning: Illegal offset type. Check your code.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to use one of the stdClass properties as key ?