# Php Illegal offset type error when running sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have 4 buttons and when clicking each one it runs different sql query.
My code is here:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
    global $wpdb; 
    $wpdb->update( $wpdb->options, array("option_value" => "000"), array("option_name" => "theme-bg"), array("%s"), array("%s") );
}elseif(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
    global $wpdb; 
    $wpdb->update( $wpdb->options, array("option_value" => "..."), array("option_name" => "widget_son_eklenenler2"), array("%s"), array("%s") );
}elseif(isset($_POST['submit3'])){
   include 'theme2.php';
}elseif(isset($_POST['submit4'])){
      include 'theme3.php';
}
?>
```

When I clicked second, third or the other buttons, it shows no warning but whenever I click the first button it gives a php warning like [image: this]

Thank you for reading it.

Comment: Which is line #724 of `acera-options/generate-options.php`?

Comment: Hello Phil, here it is. http://prntscr.com/f5oexw

Comment: That's highly unlikely. **On the server running your code**, which is line #724 of `C:\wamp64\www\wp-content\themes\whatever\acera-options\generate-options.php`?

Comment: Actually, it was normally line #740, I didnt understand why #721 on that pic.
Now it shows #740 http://prntscr.com/f5ofu2 I didnt change anything

Comment: In that case, you need to debug whatever `$value['id']` is. It's probably not a scalar value

Comment: More information here ~ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732451/php-how-do-i-fix-this-illegal-offset-type-error

Comment: I will check it out but I am not good on Php so much, here is my whole code if you can find solution in here http://textuploader.com/d9amf