# Warning: Illegal offset type error in PHP

Tags: php, json, curl, foreach

I have the data back from an API, but when I attempt to loop through the data, I always get back-

*Warning: Illegal offset type*

Here is a section of my code:

```
    $data = json_decode($data);        
    foreach($data->results as $dat){
        var_dump($data->results[$dat]);          
    }
```

I'm able to get back var_dump($dat) but that's about it.
I have never had this issue before so I am not sure what's going on.

Comment: What's the content of var_dump($data)?

Comment: Refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/q/2732451/6521116

Comment: If I var dump the data the data is returned so I know it's not an issue with the my data.

Comment: Without info, how can we find the issue.

Comment: 3rd eye might find an issue with your data or the code you wrote. Please post your printed data to check

Comment: Well  I'm able to get the data back  when I  var dump it out of the loop so I'm pretty sure it has to do with my loop

Comment: I'm using the NYT API so I can't post the whole var dump but here is a portion:

Comment: object(stdClass)#2 (6) { ["status"]=> string(2) "OK" ["copyright"]=> string(67) "Copyright (c) 2017 The New York Times Company. All Rights Reserved." ["section"]=> string(4) "home" ["last_updated"]=> string(25) "2017-05-08T22:17:51-04:00" ["num_results"]=> int(32) ["results"]=> array(32) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#184 (18) { ["section"]=> string(8) "Briefing" ["subsection"]=> string(0) "" ["title"]=> string(73)...