# Container::getAlias($abstract) throws ErrorException: Illegal offset type in isset or empty when $abstract there is not in $this->aliases[]

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

- Laravel Version: 5.6.16
- PHP Version: 7.2.3
- Database Driver & Version: N/A

#### Description:

laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php public function getAlias($abstract) 
throws ErrorException: Illegal offset type in isset or empty
when $abstract there is not in $this->aliases[]

$this->aliases[$abstract] is null and !isset($this->aliases[$abstract]) throws ErrorException: Illegal offset type in isset or empty

$abstract value is Modules\Administration\Tests\Commands\StubJsonCommandHandler

#### Steps To Reproduce:

Run AdministrationControllerTest (https://github.com/proyectotau/TAU/ clone laraveldusk branch [4ef9b0e124657abed7afde0969f332bf7be95a8b])

Is it a bug or I have any mistake? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

When binding an instance to the container, please make sure you are using:

```
app()->instance('dependency', $instantiation);
```

not,

```
app()->bind('dependency', $instantiation); // DON'T bind an instance
```

Attempting to bind an instance will result an error, as the container tries to index possible aliases using a concrete object as opposed to a type.

Answer (score 0):

#### Workaround

Change in getAlias() function
`! isset($this->aliases[$abstract])`
for
`! isset($this->aliases[(string)$abstract])`

Or change explicitly *type-hint* to `string` at ALL functions (`@param string` is not enough)
`public function getAlias($abstract)`
for
`public function getAlias(string $abstract)`

But it fails later in next use of [$abstract] in Container:

`isShared() at isset($this->instances[(string)$abstract]) isset($this->bindings[(string)$abstract]
resolve() calling to$this->resolved[(string)$abstract] = true;
getConcrete() at if (isset($this->bindings[(string)$abstract]))
getContextualConcrete() at if (empty($this->abstractAliases[(string)$abstract]))
getExtenders() at if (isset($this->extenders[(string)$abstract]))`

and in Illuminate\Foundation\Application:

`make() at if (isset($this->deferredServices[(string)$abstract]) && ! isset($this->instances[(string)$abstract]))`

PS: Please have a look to Alvaro Gonzalez's comment in
[php - How do I fix this illegal offset type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732451/php-how-do-i-fix-this-illegal-offset-type-error#comment70423941_8092350)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out the issue was send params like ::class which can not be used as an array index.
Strings must be instead