# Illegal offset type in isset or empty warning in php

Tags: php

```
if($state_id && !isset($A_CITY[$state_id][$city_name]) && isset($A_ALT[$state_id][$city_name]))
    {
      $city_name = $A_ALT[$state_id][$city_name];
      $catSearchParams['City'] = $city_name;
    }
```

> I am getting warning on first line.
>
> Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty

Comment: either your $state_id or $city_name variables have not been assigned or they have been assigned a 'null' value. Indexing into an array with a 'null' value is an illegal offset.

Comment: It must be `$city_name`, since the `if` statement checks that `$state_id` is non-null.

Comment: What does `var_dump($city_name)` show?

Comment: SO what could be the solution, i mean $state_id has some value and $city_name also has some value.  but ya $A_CITY[$state_id][$city_name] gives no output.

Comment: @Barmar: I didnt understood

Comment: You're wrong, `$city_name` must be `null` or you wouldn't get this error.

Comment: You're assigning to `$city_name` *after* the `if` statement.

Comment: What does `var_dump($city_name)` show **before** the `if` statement?

Comment: Dnt go inside IF loop, as it has some other logic.

Comment: @Barmar: var_dump($city_name) before if loop dnt give any output. i mean null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check that `$city_name` is not null before trying to use it as an index, just like you do with `$state_id`.

```
if($state_id && $city_name && !isset($A_CITY[$state_id][$city_name]) && isset($A_ALT[$state_id][$city_name]))
{
  $city_name = $A_ALT[$state_id][$city_name];
  $catSearchParams['City'] = $city_name;
}
```

Comment: The other possibility is that `$city_name` is set, but it's not a string or integer. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732451/php-how-do-i-fix-this-illegal-offset-type-error?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score -1):

```
if($state_id && !isset($A_CITY[(string)$state_id][(string)$city_name]) && isset($A_ALT[(string)$state_id][(string)$city_name]))
{
  $city_name = $A_ALT[$state_id][$city_name];
  $catSearchParams['City'] = $city_name;
}
```