# Illegal offset type in C:\MAMP\htdocs\wp592\wp-admin\includes\template.php on line 1660

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

i've been following a wordpress plugin tutorial but can't seem to figure out this error i'm getting.

SettingsApi.php

```
<?php 

/**
 * Plugin Name: johns web project
 * * Description:  Handles the custom functions for the hans site
 * 
 * @package JohnPlugin
 */

 namespace Inc\API;

class SettingsApi
{
    public $admin_pages = array();

    public $admin_subpages = array();

    public $settings = array();

    public $sections = array();

    public $fields = array();

    public function register()
    {
        if ( ! empty( $this->admin_pages ) ){
            add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'addAdminMenu' ) );
        }

        if ( !empty($this->settings) ){
            add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'registerCustomFields' ) );
        }
    }

    public function AddPages( array $pages )
    {
        $this->admin_pages = $pages;

        return $this;
    }

    public function withSubPage( string $title = null ) {
        if ( empty($this->admin_pages) ) {

            return $this;
        }

        $admin_page = $this->admin_pages[0];

        $subpage = array(
              array(
                    'parent_slug' => $admin_page['menu_slug'],
                    'page_title' => $admin_page['page_title'],
                    'menu_title' => ($title) ? $title : $admin_page['menu_title'],
                    'capability' => $admin_page['capability'],
                    'menu_slug' => $admin_page['menu_slug'],
                    'callback' => $admin_page['callback'],
                    
                )
        );

        $this->admin_subpages = $subpage;

        return $this;
    }

    public function addSubPages( array $pages )

    {
        $this->admin_subpages = array_merge( $this->admin_subpages, $pages );

        return $this;
    }

    public function addAdminMenu()
    {
        foreach ($this->admin_pages as $page ){
            add_menu_page( $page['page_title'], $page['menu_title'], $page['capability'], $page['menu_slug'], $page['callback'], $page['icon_url'], $page['position']);
        }

        foreach ($this->admin_subpages as $page ){
            add_submenu_page( $page['parent_slug'], $page['page_title'], $page['menu_title'], $page['capability'], $page['menu_slug'], $page['callback']);
        }
    }

    public function setSettings( array $settings )
    {
        $this->settings = $settings;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setSections( array $sections )
    {
        $this->sections = $sections;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setFields( array $fields )
    {
        $this->fields = $fields;

        return $this;
    }

    public function registerCustomFields()
    {
        //register setting
         foreach ($this->settings as $setting ){
            register_setting( $setting["option_group"], $setting["option_name"], ( isset($setting["callback"] ) ? $setting["callback"] : '' ) );
        }
        // add settings section 
        foreach ($this->sections as $section ){
            add_settings_section( $section["id"], $section["title"], ( isset( $section["callback"] ) ? $section["callback"] : '' ), $section["page"] );
        }
        // add settings field
        foreach ($this->fields as $field ){
            add_settings_field( $field["id"], $field["title"], ( isset( $field["callback"] ) ? $field["callback"] : '' ),  $field["section"], ( isset( $field["args"] ) ? $field["args"] : '' ) );

        }
    }
}
```

Admin.php

```
<?php 

/**
 * Plugin Name: johns web project
 * * Description:  Handles the custom functions for the hans site
 * 
 * @package JohnPlugin
 */

 namespace Inc\Pages;

 use \Inc\Api\SettingsApi;
 use \Inc\Base\BaseController;
use \Inc\Api\Callbacks\AdminCallbacks;

 class Admin extends BaseController 
{
    public $settings;

    public $callbacks;

    public $pages = array();

    public $subpages = array();


    public function register() {

        $this->settings = new SettingsApi();

        $this->callbacks = new AdminCallbacks();

        $this->setPages();

        $this->setSubPages();

        $this->setSettings();

        $this->setSections();

        $this->setFields();


        $this->settings->addPages( $this->pages )->withSubPage( 'Dashboard' )->addSubPages( $this->subpages )->register();

    }
   
    public function setPages() 
    {

         $this->pages = array(
            
                array(
                    'page_title' => 'John Plugin',
                    'menu_title' => 'John',
                    'capability' => 'manage_options',
                    'menu_slug' => 'john_plugin',
                    'callback' => array( $this->callbacks, 'adminDashboard'),
                    'icon_url' => 'dashicons-store',
                    'position' => 110
                ),
             
            
        );
    }

    public function setSubPages()
    {
         $this->subpages = array(
            array(
                'parent_slug' => 'john_plugin',
                'page_title' => 'Custom Post Types',
                'menu_title' => 'CPT',
                'capability' => 'manage_options',
                'menu_slug' => 'john_cpt',
                'callback' => array( $this->callbacks, 'cptManager')
            ),
            array(
                'parent_slug' => 'john_plugin',
                'page_title' => 'Custom Taxonomies',
                'menu_title' => 'Taxonomies',
                'capability' => 'manage_options',
                'menu_slug' => 'john_taxonomies',
                'callback' => array( $this->callbacks, 'taxonomiesManager')
            ),
            array(
                'parent_slug' => 'john_plugin',
                'page_title' => 'Custom Widgets',
                'menu_title' => 'Widgets',
                'capability' => 'manage_options',
                'menu_slug' => 'john_widgets',
                'callback' => array( $this->callbacks, 'widgetsManager')
            ),
        );
    }

    public function setSettings()
    {
        $args = array(
            array(
                'option_group' => 'john_options_group',
                'option_name' => 'text_example',
                'callback' => array( $this->callbacks, 'johnOptionsGroup' )
            )
        );

        $this->settings->setSettings( $args );
    }
    public function setSections()
    {
        $args = array(
            array(
                'id' => 'john_admin_index',
                'title' => 'Settings',
                'callback' => array( $this->callbacks, 'johnAdminSection' ),
                'page' => 'john_plugin'
            )
        );

        $this->settings->setSections( $args );
    }
    
    public function setFields()
    {
        $args = array(
            array(
                'id' => 'text_example',
                'title' => 'Settings',
                'callback' => array( $this->callbacks, 'johnTextExample' ),
                'page' => 'john_plugin',
                'section' => 'john_admin_index',
                'args' => array(
                    'label_for' => 'text_example',
                    'class' => 'example-class'
                )
            )
        );

        $this->settings->setFields( $args );
    }

 }
```

AdminCallbacks.php

```
 <?php 
    
    /**
     * Plugin Name: johns web project
     * * Description:  Handles the custom functions for the hans site
     * 
     * @package JohnPlugin
     */
    
     namespace Inc\API\Callbacks;
    
    use Inc\Base\BaseController;
    
    class AdminCallbacks extends BaseController
    {
        public function adminDashboard(){
             return require_once( "$this->plugin_path/templates/admin.php" );
        }
    
        public function cptManager(){
              echo '<h1>CPT Manager</h1>'; 
        }
    
        public function taxonomiesManager(){
              echo '<h1>Taxonomies Manager</h1>'; 
        }
    
        public function widgetsManager(){
              echo '<h1>Widgets Manager</h1>';
        }
    
        public function johnOptionsGroup( $input ){
            return $input;
        }
    
        public function johnAdminSection(){
            echo 'Check this beautiful section!';
        }
    
        public function johnTextExample(){
            $value = esc_attr( get_option( 'text_example' ) );
            echo '<input type="text" class="regular-text" name="text_example" value="' . $value . '" placeholder="Write Something Here!"> ' ;
        }
    
    }
```

any help would be appericated. Still new to wordpress and building plugins.I've tried searching on google and youtube and commented where i'm learning to build the plugin but to no avail i can not seem to figure it out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2732502/1427345

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out. in the settingsApi file. I forgot to add $field["page"] in the add_settings_field.